# Why is bower_components folder missing when I open a new angularjs project using WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I have created a WebStorm project which works, but when I open a new WebStorm project (File -> New Project) the folder "bower-components" disappear and so I can't reference "angular.js"

That's what I see:

[image: bower.json exists]

Comment: Does the folder exist on your file system? Is it ignored? There are way too many possible reasons for this.

Comment: It doesn't exist at all. It doesn't exist in the file system of new WebStorm project, while in the first project at all that I had created, it exists in the file system and it is recognized by WebStorm.

Comment: It doesn't exist by default. Run `bower install [package-you-want]` and Bower will then create the folder and download the package into it.

Comment: "bower" is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: Then you haven't even installed Bower. Check their website for [instructions](http://bower.io/#install-bower).

Answer (score 2):

When you open a new project, it has no bower.json. So start with :

```
 bower init
```

This will ask you a set of questions. Post that, you need to add angular dependencies, do:

```
bower install angular --save
```

This will add a new entry in your bower.json under dependencies.

You have to do the same for other dependencies as well.

Comment: do `npm install bower` and if it says the same for npm then goto nodejs.org and get node and npm.